# Megascan object, viewport shadow is odd black

Tags: 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, shadows

Updated:
Here is my packed Blender file:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18oEstq5oBS_6ILUNNtZeRxpP4Fthnnhx?usp=sharing

Thanks to Lemon!

---

Hi everyone,

I've been trying to import Megascan objects into Blender, and got odd shadows (please see attached).

Was wondering if anyone knows the reason, please?

Here are some detailed information -

The render engine I'm trying is Eevee. Changing the Viewport Sampling number doesn't make any difference.

I tried both the Material Preview and the Rendered Preview, they look exactly the same.

I cracked up 'Render Properties > Shadows> Cube Size & Cascale Size' both to be 2048 px. Still the same result.

---

Cycles looks fine. My only problem is with Eevee.

---

I'm attaching screen shots of my Viewport, the Material Nodes, the World Nodes, and the Megascan object I downloaded through Bridge. I don't know what else I should check to fix this. Hope someone can help!

Thank you very very much in advance!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

enter image description here

[image: The megascan object]

Comment: tuning a bit the strength of the normal map node? if not, please share a blend file with textures included (packed into the file: file/external data/pack all into blend).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input!!! I have tried to change the normal node - still the same result. I'll be trying to upload the files.

Comment: Just uploaded my files to Google Drive. Many thanks!!

Comment: Liz, your file needs an authorization to be loaded... can you change that? Or upload it here https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Oh sorry! I just changed the authorization. Hope the link works now. I'm also trying to upload the file to blend-exchange.com (thank you for the info!!) It seems it'll take some time.

Comment: ok, in the plane shader (name is Thai_Trampled_Beach_vb2jbgdlw), the normal map node has its output linked to 'alpha'. Set it to 'normal' instead.

Comment: Something came up yesterday. I checked your reply early today morning. And I didn't have a chance to reply until now. Anyways - sorry for the delay. I can't say thank enough to you!!! Really, really, really appreciate your time and your help. Yes, everything is fine now. Cheers!!